# Using SQL to match multiple items based on selection data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to use SQL within Access 2016 to return a list of registry entries from one table that are not contained within another registry entry table.

This seems simple on the surface, but the registry entries can repeat.  The registry entries are tied to a reusable part serial number that is how we designate builds on the production floor.

One table (`UsageData`) has a registry entry (`"250454"`) and a product completion date (`6/14/2019`), and contains machine usage date (times, usage codes, comments).

The other table (`RegisterType`) has a registry entry (`"250454"`) and a product completion date (`6/14/2019`), but contains what kind of product reuse this was.  This product reuse data is not known at the time that the `UsageData` table data is entered, so it seems cleaner to enter it into a separate table at the end of the month rather than modifying entries in the `UsageData` table.

I would like to write a SQL query that goes through the `UsageData` table, compares what already exists in the `RegisterType` table, and finds what entries in the `UsageData` table do not have a corresponding entry in the `RegisterType` table.

If the date and register number do not **BOTH** correspond exactly, I would like it to return outstanding registers that need to be reconciled.  The register numbers can repeat, as stated above, because this is a reusable part, which complicates the matter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have attempted to both build the query using the Access query builder and writing SQL code from scratch.  I have tried a few different join types in Access/SQL and `SELECT`/`WHERE`/`CASE` statements, and have not been able to find a way around this issue.

This is built from subqueries, but just an example of some of the things I have tried.

```
SELECT AllRegisters.TorpReg, AllRegisters.LogDate
FROM AllRegisters LEFT JOIN RegisterEntered ON AllRegisters.[TorpReg] = RegisterEntered.[TorpReg]
WHERE (((RegisterEntered.TorpReg) Is Null));
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query at the moment? From what I understood from your issue, the LEFT JOIN would be the correct way to see the non-matching entries. Also, if you want the DATE and REGISTRY entry to match then you need to also make sure to include both in the `ON` statement and not just `[TorpReg]`.

Comment: Gordon, sorry, but I cannot provide actual data.  If it comes down to it I could fake some stuff.

Comment: hisoka, I will attempt that today and get back to you.  Thank you for your assistance!